# icu4c + Mapnik - I want to switch icu4c from 55.1 to 54.1 to get Mapnik to work

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mavericks, homebrew, icu, mapnik

What is the best way to downgrade icu4c from 55.1 to 54.1 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

I tried `brew switch icu4c 54.1` and failed.

**Reason to switch back to 54.1**

I am trying to setup and use Mapnik. 
I was able to install Mapnik from homebrew - `brew install mapnik`

But, I get the following error when I try to `import mapnik` in python

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from _mapnik import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik/_mapnik.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.54.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/mapnik/2.2.0_5/lib/libmapnik.dylib
  Reason: image not found`

Python version on my Mac - Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)

Is switching icu4c back to 54.1 way to go?

Or, Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This was Homebrew's fault and should be fixed after `brew update && brew upgrade mapnik`; sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but using Yosemite but I guess it should be fairly the same. I am not sure this is the best way to do it but it worked for me.

I tried `brew switch icu4c 54.1` but failed since I did not have that package in the Cellar.

My solution was getting ici4c 54.1 in the Cellar.

First check if you have the .tar file cached to do this look in  `/Library/Caches/Homebrew` for `icu4c-54.1.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz`
If it is there you can just extract it and put the 54.1 folder in `/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/` folder then run the `brew switch icu4c 54.1` command.

If you don't have the library cached you can download it from here
 https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/icu4c-54.1.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz and the same goes for putting the 54.1 folder in the correct place in the cellar and running brew switch.